# How do you write a dataframe/RDD with custom delimeiter (ctrl-A delimited) file in spark scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I am working over poc in which I need to create dataframe and then save it as ctrl A delimited file.
My query to create intermediate result is below

```
val grouped = results.groupBy("club_data","student_id_add","student_id").agg(sum(results("amount").cast(IntegerType)).as("amount"),count("amount").as("cnt")).filter((length(trim($"student_id")) > 1) && ($"student_id").isNotNull)
```

Saving result in text file

```
grouped.select($"club_data", $"student_id_add", $"amount",$"cnt").rdd.saveAsTextFile("/amit/spark/output4/")
```

Output :

```
 [amit,DI^A356035,581,1]
```

It saves data as comma separated but I need to save it as ctrl-A separate 
I tried option("delimiter", "\u0001") but seems it's not supported by dataframe/rdd.

Is there any function which helps?

Comment: You can use mkString() function on rdd and save as a text file.

Comment: Use Spark CSV to write the data. Specify `option("delimiter", "\\01")`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have a dataframe you can use Spark-CSV to write as a csv with delimiter as below.

```
df.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).option("delimiter", "\u0001").csv("outputCSV")
```

With Older version of Spark

```
df.write
    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .option("delimiter", "\u0001")
    .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
    .save("outputCSV")
```

You can read back as below

```
spark.read.option("delimiter", "\u0001").csv("outputCSV").show()
```

IF you have an RDD than you can use `mkString()` function on `RDD` and save with `saveAsTextFile()`

```
rdd.map(r => r.mkString(\u0001")).saveAsTextFile("outputCSV")
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: using csv option I am not able to compile my code                                                 Erro : "value csv is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWrite"

Comment: [ERROR] C:\Users\amit.pathak\workspace\SparkPOC\src\com\MapToSpark.scala:69: error: value csv is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter
[INFO] grouped.select($"club_data", $"student_id_add", $"amount",$"cnt").write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).option("delimiter", "\u0001").csv("/amit/spark/output6/")

Comment: do I need to import anything ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162425/discussion-between-amit-and-shankar-koirala).

Answer (score 1):

```
df.rdd.map(x=>x.mkString("^A")).saveAsTextFile("file:/home/iot/data/stackOver")
```

Comment: You are using literal `^A` instead of Ctrl-A

Answer (score 1):

convert the rows to text before saving:

```
grouped.select($"club_data", $"student_id_add", $"amount",$"cnt").map(row => row.mkString(\u0001")).saveAsTextFile("/amit/spark/output4/")
```